# Use yarn and npm in Gitlab CI

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

I have a project which runs, in Gitlab CI, Yarn v1.22.5.
Among all its dependencies, there is one which is a Github repository. It runs a `prepare` script and it has `package-lock.json` file. For that project is it used npm indeed.

When it comes to install that dependency, I can see (in the Gitlab CI console) the following warning:

```
info No lockfile found.
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
```

It seems that Yarn tries to install that dependency but it noticed the `package-lock.json` file from npm.

Is there a way to avoid this?
I would like to understand if there is a way to use npm when it comes to install that dependency.

Comment: Is the package-lock.json file committed in either repository or is it generated in the pipeline?